# T-SQL: Left Join and returning a null when no join is made

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, null

I have the following table, TableA, with some data

```
ColA  ColB
0      5
0      6
```

I have another table, TableB, with some data

```
ColC  ColD   ColE
5      10     5
5      15     10
6      20     10
```

ColC is the foreign key for ColB. For each row in TableA I need to return ColA, ColB and ColD. The row to select in TableB depends on the value of ColE that is set through a parameter.

For example: If my parameter is set to 5, I should get two rows back as follows:

```
ColA  ColB  ColD
0      5     10
0      6     null
```

However, if my parameter is anything other than 5 and no row exists in TableB, it uses a parameter value of 5 instead and retrieves the value from ColB (if a row exists).

I tried several things but can't seem to come up with the solution. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't get why you shound get 0 6 null with a parameter of 5 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select ColA, ColB, ColD
  from TableA a
  left outer join TableB b on (a.ColB = b.ColC and b.ColE = 5)
```

Comment: That is correct but unfortunately I left out something. In the above post I added "However, if my parameter is anything other than 5 and no row exists in TableB, it uses a parameter value of 5 instead and retrieves the value from ColB (if a row exists)." So if no row exists for a parameter value other than 5, then I want to fall back to a row where 5 exists (if one does exist). Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.ColA, a.ColB, COALESCE(b.ColD, b5.ColD)
  from TableA a
  left outer join TableB b 
  on a.ColB = b.ColC 
  and b.ColE = 6
  left outer join TableB b5 
  on a.ColB = b5.ColC 
  and b5.ColE = 5
```